# How to avoid string based on prefix using regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using regular expression to identify names from a student file. Names contain prefix such as 'MR' or 'MRS' or there is no prefix only name, for an example 'MR GEORGE 51' or 'MRS GEORGE 52' or 'GEORGE 53'.
I want to extract 53 only from 'GEORGE 53' out of these three(the last one), meaning no 'MR GEORGE 51' or 'MRS GEORGE 52' should come. Note: numbers can be change, its an age.

I do know about regular expression and i tried patterns like '[^M][^R]' '[^M][^R][^S]' to identify and extract age, only when no 'MR' or 'MRS' should come as a prefix in a string. I understand through python program i can achieve this by some condition but i do want to know is there any regular expression available to do the same.

Comment: Do you test against standalone strings? Try `if re.match(r'(?i)(?!mrs?\b)\S+\s\d+$', s): print(s)`. Or, even `if not s.lower().startswith('Mr') and not s.lower().startswith('Mrs'): print(s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you quick response, i have a raw text file, and i am trying your code thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as i said, through program it can be done. Is there any regular expression which can be applied directly to match and get the value only when there is no prefix like [MR], [MRS], and yes your piece of code work thank you.

Comment: So `(?i)^(?!mrs?\b)\S+\s\d+$` works for you, right? Or `^(?!MRS?\b)\S+\s\d+$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Again thanks, i did get your expression, but say we have 'mrs hales 21 mrs halen 42, halena 27' ...?

Comment: And you want to extract them? Try `re.findall(r'\b(?!mrs?\b)\S+\s\d+\b', text, re.I)`. Please let know if it is what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, your code give me all values related to name and age, retrospectively or their prefix. I think i got it could you just verify as you are an expert in these.. [^m][^a-z][^a-z]\s*anyname\s*(\d{2})

Comment: Try `print(re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bmr\s)(?<!\bmrs\s)\S+\s\d{1,2}\b', text, re.I))`, see https://ideone.com/NxrARV

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank You. thats what i needed, could you suggest is it safe to use this on 100 MB text, 1000 MB text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^M][^R]` pattern matches any char but `M` followed with any char but `R`. Thus, you may actually reject valid matches if they are `SR` or `ME`, for example.

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bmr\s)(?<!\bmrs\s)\S+\s+\d{1,2}\b', text, re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6xeUTS/2). To grab the name and age into separate tuple items capture them:

```
re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bmr\s)(?<!\bmrs\s)(\S+)\s+(\d{1,2})\b', text, re.I)
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\bmr\s)` - no `mr` + space right before the current location
- `(?<!\bmrs\s)` - no `mrs` + space right before the current location
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 2: one or two digits
- `\b` - word boundary

The `re.I` is the case insensitive modifier.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/NxrARV):

```
import re
text="for an example 'MR GEORGE 51' or 'MRS GEORGE 52' or 'GEORGE 53'"
print(re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bmr\s)(?<!\bmrs\s)\S+\s+\d{1,2}\b', text, re.I))
# => ['GEORGE 53']
print(re.findall(r'\b(?<!\bmr\s)(?<!\bmrs\s)(\S+)\s+(\d{1,2})\b', text, re.I))
# => [('GEORGE', '53')]
```